# start-stop-daemon error

Tags: command-line, ubuntu

I am running

> sstart-stop-daemon --start --exec
>   $DAEMON $ARGS

command on Ubuntu and getting the following error

> start-stop-daemon: user `p' not found

Can anyone spot the problem?

Abdul Khaliq

Comment: Can you put the whole script up.  Or at least echo out the values of $DAEMON and $ARGS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using

```
start-stop-daemon --start --exec "${DAEMON}" -- ${ARGS}
```

to ensure that `start-stop-daemon` is not attempting to interpret any of `$ARGS` but is instead passing all of them directly to `$DAEMON`.

Answer (score 4):

[ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127502/start-stop-daemon-error/8636056#answer-1127576) is right, but what there must appear is `--` before passing arguments. So the not working code above would be like this:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --exec /etc/init.d/mysql -- -u abc
```

Answer (score 0):

not unless you can tell us the values of $DAEMON and $ARGS, for starters.  It looks like somehow a -u p might be getting passed in.

I can sort of replicate this on my computer by running:

```
$ start-stop-daemon --start --exec /etc/init.d/mysql -u abc
    start-stop-daemon: user `abc' not found
    (Success)
```

(Except that I'm getting a success response as well).